# How to use more than one NGRX action that does the same thing following "action hygiene" guideline?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

If I have two or more NGRX actions that do the same thing, but are triggered at different parts of my application, can I use one action to perform this while at the same time differentiating the action string in my NGRX log?  I ask because when writing actions and trying to follow the "action hygiene" principles where actions should be specific to an event and can be readable a year later and tell the developer exactly where in the app the action was fired, I want to limit as much NGRX boilerplate as possible.

For example:  I have a "AddTodo" action.  This action can be performed in two spots in my application - one on a "Todo List" page, and the other on a "Todo Details" page.  Each action is unique to the page they are triggered from, but they do the exact same thing; they add a new Todo item to my state object.

```
const TODO_LIST = '[Todo List]';
const TODO_DETAILS = '[Todo Details]';

export const TODO_LIST_ADD = `${TODO_LIST} Add`;
export const TODO_DETAILS_ADD = `${TODO_DETAILS} Add`;

export class TodoListAdd implements Action {
    readonly type = TODO_LIST_ADD;
    constructor(public payload: Todo) { }
}

export class TodoDetailsAdd implements Action {
    readonly type = TODO_DETAILS_ADD;
    constructor(public payload: Todo) { }
}

export function todoReducer(state = initialState, action: Action): TodoState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.TODO_LIST_ADD:
        case actions.TODO_DETAILS_ADD:
            return {
                ...state,
                todo: (action as actions.TodoListAdd | actions.TodoDetailsAdd).payload,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

If wanting to keep action hygiene, is this the only way to do it?  There are two actions that do the exact same thing, the only difference is the string type that distinguishes them in the NGRX event log.  I would love it there was a way to reduce the amount of boilerplate by coupling the action creators without losing the specificity of the type.

Thanks,

Comment: From that prospective it doesn't hurt to just create this "fall through" using few "case"s in a row, it's event good to eliminate code duplication. But in current case maybe even from meaning point of view it's better to merge these two actions? For example into "ADD_TODO" and it doesn't really matter from which place you add todo, if it's the same entity and the same part of state.

Comment: @AmirArbabian *it doesn't really matter from which place you add todo*...yes, yes it does. As OP says, tying actions to unique event let’s the app be readable a year later and tell the developer exactly where in the app the action was fired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you follow good action hygiene this is the only way.

However, you could provide a context to your action as described here https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/reusable-action-creators-with-context-2a31dca98192.

Answer (score 2):

After a couple of attempts at implementing something like in the accepted answer and also at:

https://indepth.dev/posts/1407/force-good-action-hygiene-and-write-less-actions-in-ngrx-with-the-prepared-events-pattern

I found an alternate solution that fit better for me, and thought it would be good to post it here in case it would help anyone in the future. I took the idea from an issue about handling cases like this from the ngrx GitHub:

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2902#issuecomment-771194540

After working through some eslint/typescript errors, I came up with the following solution:

1. Create some helpers to deal with actions that have a special `kind` property. This property can be used in various actions throughout the app, making Good Action Hygiene a little more DRY:

```js
export type CategoryAction = Action & { kind: string; };

export function hasKind({ kind }: { kind: string }) {
  return {
    kind
  };
}

export function ofKind<T extends CategoryAction>(kind: string): OperatorFunction<Action, T> {
  return pipe(
    filter(action => ((action as unknown) as CategoryAction)?.kind === kind),
    map(action => action as T)
  );
}
```

2. Create a mixin for each action kind that you would like to use in multiple places throughout the app:

```js
export function hasNewTodo({ todo }: { todo: Todo }) {
  return {
    todo,
    ...hasKind({ kind: 'ADD_TODO' })
  };
}
```

3. Add an effect that translates any actions of that kind to a single action:

```js
// In your actions file
const addTodo = createAction(
  '[Todo API] Create Todo',
  props<{ todo: Todo }>()
);

// In your effects class
  addTodo$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofKind<CategoryAction & { todo: Todo }>('ADD_TODO'),
      concatMap(action => {
        return of(fromActions.addTodo({ todo: action.todo }));
      })
    );
  });
```

4. Add a reducer for the action from the effect:

```js
const todoReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(fromActions.addTodo, (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      todos: [
        ...state.todos,
        action.todo
      ]
    };
  })
);
```

5. Add any actions you need throughout your app:

```js
// Near your TodoList component
export const addTodo = createAction(
  '[Todo List] Add Todo',
  (payload: { todo: Todo}) => ({
    ...hasNewTodo({ todo: payload.todo })
  })
);

// Near your TodoDetails component
export const addTodo = createAction(
  '[Todo Details] Add Todo',
  (payload: { todo: Todo}) => ({
    ...hasNewTodo({ todo: payload.todo })
  })
);
```

## Pros:

- Minimal extra code to allow for similar actions throughout your app
- Uses normal ngrx constructs instead of needing to override/replace them all
- Follows open/closed principle: Adding a new action of that kind doesn't require you to edit the effect or reducer, you just add an action

## Cons:

- Requires an extra "translation" effect for each category
- Each time a Todo is added, two different actions will show up in the logs for that one action.